# XSLT attribute-transformation doubly whammy

Tags: xml

I have an XML document that I am transforming into HTML. There are a lot of unnecessary attributes that I want to omit, but there are two that I want to capture as follows:

### Source

```xml
<element att1="yes" att2="no" att3="yes">Text</element>
```

### Desired output

```xml
<span class="att1">Text</span>
```

So, if `att1` or `att2` is "yes", then create a class attribute with that attribute name; omit all other attributes, and transform the element to a span.

In the source doc, `att1` and `att2` should be mutually exclusive; if one is "yes" the other might not be present, and neither might be present.

Comment: Please say which version of XSLT you are using. We like to use XSLT 2.0+ if we can because most code becomes simpler, but there's no point if you aren't able to use 2.0.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I've got support for XSLT 2.0. I've been using XMLStarlet, which was compiled with the libxslt library, which supports XSLT 2.

Comment: No, libxslt has never supported XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Ah. Now I see that. In any case, I could install something else.

Comment: What do you want to output if neither attribute is present with the value "yes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way (XSLT 2.0+):

```
<xsl:template match="element[(@att1, @att2)='yes']">
  <span class="{name((@att1, @att2)[.='yes'][1])}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
  <!-- you haven't said what output you want if neither attribute is "yes" -->
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I had puzzled out something that also works, but this is more elegant.